# Finding the Cardinality of a set.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be the set of all continuous functions $f :[0,1] → [0,∞)$ satisfying the following condition:
$\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt \geq f(x) $ for all $ x \in [0,1]$.

Find the cardinality of the set $A$ .

I have no idea how to procede . Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the identically zero function ($f(x)=0$ for all $x$) belongs to $A$.

I will prove that $A$ has no other element.

Let $f \in A$. Then, for all $x \in [0,1]$
$$\int_0^x f(t) \ \mathrm d t \ge f(x)$$
integrating on $x$ you have
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(t) \ \mathrm d t \ \mathrm d x \ge \int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm d x$$
The first integral can be manipulated into
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(t) \ \mathrm d t \ \mathrm d x =
\int_0^1 \int_t^1 f(t) \ \mathrm d x \ \mathrm d t = \int_0^1 (1-t) f(t) \ \mathrm d t = \int_0^1 f(t) \ \mathrm d t - \int_0^1 tf(t) \ \mathrm d t$$
Thus you have
$$\int_0^1 f(t) \ \mathrm d t - \int_0^1 tf(t) \ \mathrm d t \ge \int_0^1 f(x) \ \mathrm d x$$
i.e.
$$\int_0^1 t f(t) \ \mathrm d t \le 0$$

Since $tf(t)$ is continuous and non-negative, its integral must be non-negative. Thus you have
$$0 \le \int_0^1 t f(t) \ \mathrm d t \le 0$$
which implies that $f(t)$ is identically zero.

Comment: How did you get the idea to do this ? :)

Comment: I saw a lot of tricks here at Math Stack Exchange :P. Anyway, when you are in doubt, integrate and the inequality must be preserved. Other times differentiating is a good idea: it depends on the problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think it takes time to get used to pure mathematics.

Comment: I began studying pure mathematics last year. Sometimes i feel depressed not able to solve questions. But i think that is the part of learning. :)

Comment: @Crostul  I know it's a year but if you have time please respond to this query of mine: When I tried to solve it by differentiating it,  $\int_0^x f(t) \ \mathrm d t \ge f(x) \implies f'(x) \le f(x) \implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \le 1 \implies \int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx \le \int 1 \implies log(f(x)) \le x+logc \implies f(x) \le ce^x $. Now, I think I can get a lot of functions which satisfy this. Can you tell me wherein lies the fallacy in my argument?

Comment: @adityabhatt It is ver simple to find the fallacy in your argument. It's not true that "$f \le g$ implies $f' \le g'$", thus the first arrow is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: how many continuous functions $f:[0,\,1]\mapsto [0,\,\infty)$ exist, satisfying the last condition or otherwise? (You can get an upper bound from the fact $f$ is specified by its values on $\Bbb Q\cap [0,\,1]$, and this upper bound is also an obvious lower bound by constructing a specific family of solutions.) And can you show this cardinality also lower-bounds $|A|$?